# Using R to analyze bus delays using difference between times and timetables

Tags: r

I'm having a problem with an essay.

I have a data frame with the bus stops, date and time at which it arrived at the bus stop, i don't have gps data, it is guided through a gps sinal sent every 30 seconds but it uses the bus stop id until it reaches a new one, among other fields which perhaps are not important for this question.

Then i separated the time date columns into separate columns using the command:

```
Hours <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(x$xcol,"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",tz="")) ,format = "%H:%M")
```

I was able to separate them but they are as character class. Then i uploaded the bus actual time table and it uploads as POSIXct and it brings the date and hour, and i only wanted the hours. And then i wanted to do something like diff time or something.

```
Example:

    df2$DATA_TRAMA
       [1] 25-1-2010 07:37:26  25-1-2010 07:38:24  25-1-2010 07:39:56  25-1-2010 07:41:45  25-1-2010 07:42:36 
       [6] 25-1-2010 07:43:26  25-1-2010 07:44:15  25-1-2010 07:45:44  25-1-2010 07:46:57  25-1-2010 07:47:47 
      [11] 25-1-2010 07:49:04  25-1-2010 07:50:15  25-1-2010 07:51:46  25-1-2010 07:52:27  25-1-2010 07:54:22 
      [16] 25-1-2010 07:55:09  25-1-2010 07:57:12  25-1-2010 08:00:07  25-1-2010 08:01:11  25-1-2010 08:02:45 
      [21] 25-1-2010 08:06:38  25-1-2010 08:13:33  25-1-2010 08:17:55  25-1-2010 08:19:42  25-1-2010 08:20:40 
      [26] 25-1-2010 08:22:46  25-1-2010 08:25:35  25-1-2010 08:26:17  25-1-2010 08:28:01  25-1-2010 08:29:42
```

Above is the result for a date time column which i want to separate because i'm mostly interested in the time only

To separate them i use the commands:

```
Hours <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(df2$DATA_TRAMA,"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",tz="")) ,format = "%H:%M")
#output "15:44" "23:24" "19:15" "20:52" "07:46" "01:55"

Dates <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(df2$DATA_TRAMA,"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M",tz="")) ,format = "%d-%m-%Y")
#output "27/27/2015" "23/23/2015" "31/31/2015" "20/20/2015" "23/23/2015" "31/31/2015"

df2$Dates <- Dates
df2$Hours <- Hours
```

And the class is as appears, character.

```
str(df2$Dates)
 chr [1:1088222] "25-01-2010" "25-01-2010" "25-01-2010" "25-01-2010" "25-01-2010" "25-01-2010" ...
```

But what i want is it to be POSIXct or similar in order to apply difftimes and see time differences to see what was the delay.

As for the timetable i have a data frame just for that, which is imported already as POSIXct

```
str(horidat)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   75 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ CORD4: POSIXct, format: "1899-12-31 06:25:00" "1899-12-31 06:45:00" "1899-12-31 07:00:00" ...
 $ PRL8 : POSIXct, format: "1899-12-31 06:26:00" "1899-12-31 06:46:00" "1899-12-31 07:01:00" ...
 $ PRDJ2: POSIXct, format: "1899-12-31 06:28:00" "1899-12-31 06:48:00" "1899-12-31 07:03:00" ...
 $ SCAT1: POSIXct, format: "1899-12-31 06:29:00" "1899-12-31 06:49:00" "1899-12-31 07:04:00" ...
```

But for the horidat data frame (timetable) i wanted it to have only the time as well without changing the class. The problem is that i only know how to do it in the same way as above, which then also changes into character.

After that i would like to see the difference between the times in order to see the delay. But to do that they both have to be in the same format right? I think that to use the function `difftime` they have to  be POSIXct right?

When i try to convert one of them i get the following errors:

```
df2$Hours<-as.POSIXct(df2$Hours)
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

My problem is to convert these variables into the proper format so i can use them, whenever i try to calculate the difference between times and as such the delays.

Does any one know how i could overcome this issue?

Comment: I don't know if I understand but if you want only the hours, you can change the format with format = "%H". However, post a toys data :)

Comment: Hi! My question is how to convert a column to "%H:%M" and maintain the  class POSIXct or POSIXlt in data frame x, and then do the same for the timetable but only with the hours and minutes for each bus stop, because it automatically adds the date, and i didn't want that

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I cannot tell what you want to do

Comment: @mathematical.coffee, i'll try to leave here the example: